# Juno Winehq problem

Tags: wine, release-juno

Regardless of whether I am trying to install wine through applications or the terminal, I get an error. Does anyone have the same problem?

> Some packages could not be installed. It can mean
>   that an impossible situation has been requested or unstable distribution has been used in which some packages have not yet been created or transferred
>   from Incoming.

Thank you for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having issues earlier tonight installing wine-staging on Elementary OS Juno following WineHQ's install instructions.  I found this [Juno Install Guide by itsjaredbs](https://gist.github.com/itsjaredbs/5fbb1c65e0799d2aa9bc0dacc9945624#wine-staging) and his instructions worked. Hope this works for you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, after struggling for a while:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install wine-staging-i386
sudo apt -y install --install-recommends wine-staging
sudo apt -y install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Then reboot. If anything bad happens, try this:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: Im still getting the broken packages error. https://imgur.com/wH1p8lz